# Bootsrap 3 Remote Modal Send Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, parameter-passing, bootstrap-modal

currently I am working on modification Remote Modal (show href in modal).

```
<a id="btnAdd" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#DetailModal" data-tot="60" href="http://urlmodal">
```

on javascript I have

```
$('#DetailModal').on("loaded.bs.modal", function (e) {
        alert($(e.relatedTarget).data('tot'));
        });
```

I wanna to catch variable "data-tot" in link (button), but it result undefined. either `$(e.relatedTarget).data('tot')` or `$(e).data('tot')` result undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Found it, I need to iterate show then loaded to catch then put in remote modal

```
$('#DetailModal').on("show.bs.modal", function (e) {
         var dtot = $(e.relatedTarget).data('tot');
            $('#DetailModal').on("loaded.bs.modal", function (e) {
            $(e.target).find('#infoTot').html(dtot);
            });
        });
```